# If-Condition with multiple actions in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to use If-Condition with multiple actions in Robot Framework

```
${x}    Set Variable    5   
Run Keyword If  ${x} == 5       
... ${Test1} =  Set Variable    MyName
... ${Test2} =  Set Variable    MyLastName
... Else        
... ${Test1} =  Set Variable    MyAddress
... ${Test2} =  Set Variable    MyTelephone
```

But it is not working
Error show FAIL : Variable '${Test1}' not found.
Could you please tell me about using IF-Condition with multiple actions

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Run Keywords" keyword to perform multiple actions in IF condition

Kindly go through below link:

[IF ELSE in robot framework with variables assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464174/if-else-in-robot-framework-with-variables-assignment/41480516#41480516)

Comment: oh, my.  RF guys really think  this kind of syntax better than raw python syntax? Why not just use python to write test cases? IMO, that's much easier.

Comment: @Jcyrss I guess that conditional statements were added as an afterthought, and had to shoehorned into the existing syntax. Note that "If" has to written with a lowercase "f", while "ELSE" needs to be all caps. Yep, fits into the syntax scheme, but is...uh..."unconventional". So far, I am very happy that the WHILE statement, which was promised quite a few years ago, has not yet crossed my way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either cover both actions with one custom keyword and then call `Run Keyword If` or call the keyword `Set Variable If` twice or write such logic into python (jython...) library.

Answer (score 1):

Please notice "And" while using "Run Keywords"; also ensure tab used.

```
Run Keyword If  <condition1>  <action1>
    ...   ELSE IF  <condition1>
    ...   Run Keywords
    ...   <action1>
    ...   AND  <action2>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Test Variable    ${temp}    rxu
Run Keyword if    '${temp}'=='rxu'
...    Run Keywords
...    Log To Console    this is one
...    AND    Log To Console    This is two
...    ELSE    Run Keyword    Log To Console    another block
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer following keyword :

```
Run Keyword If  ${x} == 5     Set Variable    MyName
Run Keyword If  ${x} == 1     Set Variable    LastName
```

Or

```
Run Keyword If  ${x} == 5     Set Variable    MyName
... ELSE IF  ${x} == 2        Set Variable    MyName
... ELSE IF  ${x} == 3        Set Variable    Middle Name
```